# JQuery replaceWith() only work once in if condition

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I am trying to use the JQuery replaceWith() method to replace some html based on a condition in a text box.  But it will only work once and no matter the value of the text box, it always returns the same message "Replacement Effective" which is the first value in the if-else statement I have below. I need it to return a different message based on the value of the text box.

My html is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        function changeCAT() {
            var choice = $('#choice').val()
            if (choice = 'Effectiveness') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Effective!</div>'); }
            else if (choice = 'Safety') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Safe!</div>'); }
            else if (choice = 'Efficiency') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Efficient!</div>'); }
            else { alert('Please make a valid choice'); }
        };
        $('#btn').click(changeCAT);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="choice">
    <option value="effectiveness">Effectiveness</option>
    <option value="safety">Safety</option>
    <option value="efficiency">Efficiency</option>
</select>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Change Div"></form>
<div id="avg_scores">
    Original Div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use double equal `==` for comparison, not single equal `=` which is an assignment not a comparison in if condition like following:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  function changeCAT() {

    var choice = $('#choice').val()

    if (choice == 'effectiveness') {
      $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Effective!</div>');
    } else if (choice == 'safety') {
      $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Safe!</div>');
    } else if (choice == 'efficiency') {
      $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Efficient!</div>');
    } else {
      alert('Please make a valid choice');
    }
  }

  $('#btn').click(changeCAT);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option value="effectiveness">Effectiveness</option>
  <option value="safety">Safety</option>
  <option value="efficiency">Efficiency</option>
</select>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Change Div" />
<div id="avg_scores">Original Div</div>
```

Comment: Won't work.  Now it just defaults to the alert message at the end saying "Please make a valid choice"

Comment: Case sesitive is important while checking for if else condition

Comment: @user2907249 make sure you use trim() and case sensitive comparison while checking.

Comment: Ah I see.  Silly of me.  I was taking the value actually in the text box rather than the 'value' property of the option.

Answer (score 0):

Please use == instead of = operator and also you need to take care of case sensitive while checking, instead of 'Effectiveness' use 'effectiveness' in your if condition.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function changeCAT() {
        var choice = $('#choice').val()
        if (choice == 'effectiveness') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Effective!</div>'); }
        else if (choice == 'safety') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Safe!</div>'); }
        else if (choice == 'efficiency') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Efficient!</div>'); }
        else { alert('Please make a valid choice'); }
    };
    $('#btn').click(changeCAT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
    function changeCAT() {
        var choice = $('#choice').val()
        if (choice == 'effectiveness') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Effective!</div>'); }
        else if (choice == 'safety') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Safe!</div>'); }
        else if (choice == 'efficiency') { $('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div id = "avg_scores">Replacement Efficient!</div>'); }
        else { alert('Please make a valid choice'); }
    };
    $('#btn').click(changeCAT);
});
```

use  `==` for `comparasion` & `=` for `assifnment`.  Also compare it with option value attribute